# How to select from core data with multiple filters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

From what I have found online it seemed as if this would be the way to select from core data on multiple values.  I want to get everything from exercises where machineName = var1 or machineName = var2...  For whatever reason nothing is returned after I debug past the executeFetchRequest selector and equiptmentData is empty.  Also I do not get any errors.  Any help or suggestions is much appreciated and thanks in advance.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Exercises" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSMutableArray *predicates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0; i < [checked count]; i++)
{
    if([[checked objectAtIndex:i] boolValue] == YES)
    {
         NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"machineName == %@", itemArray[i]];
        [predicates addObject: predicate];
    }
}
NSArray *predicatesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: predicates];
NSPredicate * compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicatesArray];

fetchRequest.predicate = compoundPredicate;

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *equiptmentData = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error: &error];
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is the right way to do this I was not inserting into core data properly